# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" when using Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Cloud Functions for Firebase, and I am trying to use them with the Realtime Database.

I am following [this documentation where it has a Youtube tutorial at the top of the page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events).

Here is my code I have in `index.ts`:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const onMessageCreate = functions.database
.ref('/party/{partyID}/messages/{message}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const messageData = snapshot.val()
    const text = addMore(messageData.text)
    return snapshot.ref.update({ text: text })
})

function addMore(text: string): string {
    return text.replace(/\bhello\b/g, 'hey')
}
```

However, I get the following error in my functions logs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

at addMore (/user_code/lib/index.js:12:16)
at exports.onMessageCreate.functions.database.ref.onCreate (/user_code/lib/index.js:8:18)
at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:733:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

[image]

My database structure which I'm pretty sure is correct looks like this:

[image]

What is causing this error? Is some 'package' of functions not installed?

I am running node v10.9.0 and npm 6.2.0.

**Edit for Doug:**

Thank you Doug, it was a great video!  I have edited my database which now looks like this when I add a message (and previous tries where my functions attempts to replace the word):

[image]

I also changed the `TypeScript` code ref by adding `/text` to the end. I also casted `messageData` to a string using `String()` which removes the errors and shows the words as you described, 'undefined'. I have separated the messages with children as you said, but I am still puzzled on why I am not receiving the value and why it is adding an extra `text` child. Thanks!

---

**If you have any questions, please let me know!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in the end is set my database up like this:

[image]

I got my value from the database like this to make it a `string`:

```
String(snapshot.child('text').val())
```

Also, at first, in `return snapshot.ref.update({ text: text })` that `'text'` was a parameter that will appear in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you passed an undefined value to `addMore`.  You're then trying to call a string method on that undefined value.

The reference pattern you're using doesn't match your database schema.  It looks like you're assuming that each message exists as its own property in the database.  This isn't going to work the way you expect, and it's almost certainly not the database model you want to use.  Instead, you should probably be pushing new child into the database for each message, which has its own child for the text of the message.

```
/party
  /{partyid}
    /messages
      /{messageid}      //  You're missing this message id in the db
        /text = "foo"
```

Comment: I have left an update in my question, as I am still a bit puzzled. It's great to know you help as well as make the videos :)